# How to restart Flask server when using Google Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-endpoints

I followed https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-endpoints and everything worked without any issues. My question is when I update the Flask servers code how can I restart the Flask server? I know if I re-run `./deploy_app.sh` inside of the scripts folder it will re-deploy the app again but it takes a long time to do that. There must be a faster way to restart just the Flask server? If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to this [`deploy_app.sh`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-quickstart/blob/master/scripts/deploy_app.sh) script, it is indeed the only way to update and restart your app, as you must deploy it to do so, and this takes a bit of time.

If you are worried about this downtime, maybe your app is in production or something, you may edit the line `gcloud -q app deploy $APP` in the script, to be something like `gcloud -q app deploy --no-stop-previous-version $APP`. This new flag avoids stopping the previous version while you deploy the new one

Comment: Yeah I ended up using that same command which is great if you do not want down time but it still requires building a new version. Basically I just need to fully develop it locally. Thank you for the answer!